# How to group nodes based on weight in Cytoscape cola

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, webcola

I am having trouble using cytoscape with cola.
I would like a network where nodes with "heavy" edges connecting them
tend to stick closer to one another.
So far, my javascript code looks like this:

```
    var elems = [
    {data: {id: '1', name: 'Node 1', nodecolor: '#88cc88'}},
    {data: {id: '2', name: 'Node 2', nodecolor: '#888888'}},
    {data: {id: '3', name: 'Node 3', nodecolor: '#888888'}},
    {data: {id: '4', name: 'Node 4', nodecolor: '#888888'}},
    {data: {id: '5', name: 'Node 5', nodecolor: '#888888'}},
    {data: {id: 'e1', source: '1', target: '5', linkcolor: '#888888', "weight":50 } },
    {data: {id: 'e2', source: '3', target: '4', linkcolor: '#888888', "weight":30} },
    {data: {id: 'e3', source: '2', target: '1', linkcolor: '#888888', "weight":20} },
    {data: {id: 'e4', source: '1', target: '4', linkcolor: '#888888', "weight":100} },
    {data: {id: 'e5', source: '5', target: '2', linkcolor: '#888888', "weight":100} },
    {data: {id: 'e6', source: '1', target: '2', linkcolor: '#888888', "weight":40} }
];
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: elems,
    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
            .selector('node').style({
                'background-color': 'data(nodecolor)',
                label: 'data(name)',
                width: 25,
                height: 25
            })
            .selector('edge').style({
                'line-color': 'data(linkcolor)',
                width: 3
            })
});
cy.layout({name: 'cola',
           infinite: true,
           fit: false,
           padding: 10,
           edgeLength: function( edge ){var len = edge.data('weight'); return 10/len; }});
```

As you can see, I tried to change the edgeLength parameter to be proportionally inverse to the "weight" property of the edges, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Given your equation, how many pixels long would you expect each edge to be?

Comment: I see what you mean, but I just put random numbers in this case because changing them is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

You must use a formula that returns sensible lengths for edges.  Your formula returns lengths less than one pixel for all edges.  That's an impossible restriction, especially considering that [Cola supports options like `avoidOverlap` and `nodeSpacing`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cytoscape-cola#api).

A more appropriate formula would be something like `edge => k / edge.data('weight')` where `k` is something around the order of magnitude of `10000` -- you chose `k = 10`.  `k = 10000` gives e4 a length of 100 and e3 a length of 500, for example.

In order to use a layout effectively, it is important to carefully review all the layout options and make sure you set them appropriately for the result you want.